# List of tables when dealing with table inside figure

Tags: tables, floats

I'm in bit of a problem when dealing with my homework. I'm suppose to create the document with few figures (images) and the tables. Images are properly rendered in the last pages. However, one table is kind of complex because its actual dual table:

[image: duo table]

It's beign created using the code:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp] 
  \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|}
    \hline 
    UserNum & UserName & UserSurname \\
    \hline
    1001 & Adam & Nowak \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular} 
  \quad
  \begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
    \hline 
    OSType & UserUserNum \\
    \hline
    iOS 7 & 1000 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular} 
  \caption{Hierarchy model}
  \label{tab:table1}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is, I have the \listoffigures and \listoftables at the end. Table is in bad list and the whole list of tables is empty, I want it to be inside tables, not figures.

Any ideas how to handle that?

Comment: your question isn't so clear but I think you want `\begin{table}` rather than `\begin{figure}`

Comment: Dear god.. you are right, I fought with documentation pointlessly for about hour and half and this pretty much solved the issue. Table is working as before and is present in the \listoftables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `\begin{table}` rather than `\begin{figure}`